# Files deleted and disk checking

Tags: hard-drive, windows-11, pci, microsoft, hp

So my files have been permanently deleted because my laptop kept telling me to sign out and when I do my files keep getting deleted. I switched off my laptop and it started to have a disk check. There wasn't anything like skip by pressing any key, it just went straight to it immediately I switched it on. I tried switching it on and off and there are some moments when it will show repairing your drive this might take a few hours. My deleted files and this are taking a heavy till on me and I need to use the laptop in two days and with the way the disk drive is taking it's time I'm not so sure when it would be done. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I do not get the relationship between the "deleted files" problem (and which problem it is exactly) and the "disk repair" problem. You should focus your question on one particular problem.

Comment: You probably have a failing hard drive. First, backup your data, all of it. Second, if you have a warranty you should use it. Third, if you don't have a warranty, buy a new hard drive: they're not hard to install, but you may also want to have a competent local computer tech look at the system.